# LED Programme where it delays the amount written in the Serial Monitor

Tags: code-optimization

I have written a simple code to delay the blinking of LED 13, the delay time is set by us.I have incurred a problem when I enter a 2 digit value in the serial monitor.There is some problem with the ASCII. Is there a way to solve this problem without using `Serial.parseInt()`.

```c++
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Programming is starting"); 
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    int val=Serial.read();
    int val1=val-'0';
    Serial.println(val1);
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    delay(val1*1000);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  }  
}
```

Comment: [Blink without delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay).

Comment: I know this .But i want to use ascii for 2 digit.

Comment: It does not use serial monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have.

No error checking. Anything not digit produce zero as output.

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Programming is starting");
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    static int value = 0;

    while(Serial.available() > 0) {
        int c = Serial.read();

        if(isDigit(c)) {
            value = value * 10 + (c - '0');
        } else {
            Serial.println(value);
            digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
            delay(value*1000);
            digitalWrite(13,LOW);
            value = 0;
        }
    }
```

It convert chars to values as they are being readed, one by one. There are no size limit for the input string, other that final value must fit in an `int`

You write a value in the Serial Monitor and end it with return, space bar or whatever non digit key you want.